# See full redirect path and HTTP status code in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, http-headers

I'm trying to find out of a certain link shorteners and out.php linkscripts redirect using 301 redirect or not. I'm looking at the resources tab in Chrome's developer tools, but it only shows headers for the target page and not for the link scripts itself.

Also, some of the sites I'm investigating actually redirect more than once, so it'd be best if I could track the entire redirect path.

How can I see if how I was exactly redirected, and if they were using 301 or not?

Comment: Method for redirects persistency with FF : http://superuser.com/questions/242138/how-to-track-url-redirects-in-browser

Comment: stopping by breakpoint and takinging all the time you... ➝ http://stackoverflow.com/a/12419326/444255

Answer (score 166, accepted):

### Since 2014

At the top of Chrome's inspector (in the `Network` tab) is a checkbox which says `Preserve log`. Enable this option. Now it doesn't matter at all how the page navigates, the inspector will keep all log history -- including the redirect response.

### Older versions of Chrome

At the bottom of Chrome's inspector (in the `Network` tab) is a button with a big circle. Hover over this button and a tooltip says `Preserve log upon navigation`. Click the button and it will turn red. Now it doesn't matter at all how the page navigates, the inspector will keep all log history -- including the redirect response.

Comment: This is now (actually, has been for a while) a more relevant answer than the originally accepted one. I accepted this one instead.

Comment: Note, if you're tracing redirects for XHR or some kind of REST calls, and cannot see 301 or 302 redirects -  be sure that in the "Network tab" you have enabled not only "XHR" filter, but _also_ filter "Other"  (you can select multiple ones via Ctrl + Click).  Of course you can always use "All" filter, but it will have a lot of noise from other request types.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue and found the solution differed slightly to previous answers.

I had to select Other for the document type in the filter bar, as well as have preserve log ticked and record network log on.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Screenshot]

Comment: 302 Redirects only show when Other is selected (as of Google Chrome 67 on mac os 10.13)

Comment: thanks for that, I was filtering to Doc and was really confused why it wasn't showing up.

Answer (score 17):

In Chrome's developer tools - select "Resources" - then under either "Documents" or "Other" you should be able to find the original request- view the "Headers" to see status code of 301.  There's a great article here - http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/developertools/part1/#toc-resources

Comment: When a page is refreshed by javascript or meta refresh it won't track.  I did get what I needed though, so thanks :)

Comment: You can now see this in the Network area, with Status being one of the columns in the table.

Comment: Quick note that "Preserve log upon Navigation" should be enabled to see each request/response

Comment: The Resources panel has been renamed to the Application panel. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39089208/2288547